# Can i use for loop by adding 30 minutes each time while adding time to different Rows

Tags: c#

I have 10 rows with 2 columns `InTime` and `OutTime`. The `OutTime` of previous entry is `InTime` of the next entry and `OutTime` of the next entry 
should be 30 minutes more than previous `OutTime` entry. I am trying the following code:

```
TimeSpan InTime = TimeSpan.Parse("08:00");
TimeSpan t2 = TimeSpan.Parse("00:30:00");
TimeSpan OutTime = InTime.Add(t2);
```

Is there a way we can achieve this using for loop in C#?

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: i want 10 entries now but it could increase in future as a result  i don't want to use array

Comment: Question description is not very clear IMO and the for loop is not that hard to write. The Timespan also has some methods that i prefer to use instead of parsing: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(value); TimeSpan.FromMinutes(value); TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value); etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. You can set the start time, the difference, and the number of entries, and it will generate them for you. The second loop is just for testing, so you can remove it once done texting. The entries are held in a dictionary.

```
TimeSpan StartTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(8);
int Difference = 30; //In minutes.
int EntriesCount = 10;
Dictionary<TimeSpan, TimeSpan> Entries = new Dictionary<TimeSpan, TimeSpan>();

for(int i = 0; i < EntriesCount; i++){
    Entries.Add(StartTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Difference * i)),
                StartTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Difference * i + Difference)));
}

foreach(var e in Entries){
    Console.WriteLine("In: " + e.Key + " - Out: " + e.Value);
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xqhJJ0)

Comment: Thank you it did work exactly what i was looking for. I avoided using seconds as my application takes only hours and minutes. The following code work for me

Answer (score 3):

You should post an example of what you expect the table to look like... Also a little context behind what you're trying to do would go a long way. However, I'm guessing you want a table that looks something like this:

```
InTime | OutTime
-------|--------
 8:00  |  8:30
 8:30  |  9:00
 9:00  |  9:30
 9:30  | 10:00
10:00  | 10:30
10:30  | 11:00
  etc. |   etc.
```

If this is the case then you can make a pretty simple `for` loop to do so:

```
List<MyClass> rows = new List<MyClass>();

// Change the 10 in the following line to increase the number of rows.
for(double i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    TimeSpan inTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(8 + i / 2);
    TimeSpan outTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(8 + (i + 1) / 2);
    rows.Add(new MyClass(inTime, outTime));
}
```

Comment: This will not give half hours, because of integer division truncating the decimals.

Comment: @Frank Typo fixed, the iterator should've been declared a double.

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me based on the comment posted by Racil Hilan

```
TimeSpan StartTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(5);
int Difference = 15;
int EntriesCount = count;
Dictionary<TimeSpan, TimeSpan> Entries = new Dictionary<TimeSpan, TimeSpan>();

for (int TableRowId = 0; TableRowId <= count - 1; TableRowId++)
{
     string inTime = "//*[@id='INTIME" + TableRowId + "']";
     string outTime = "//*[@id='OUTTIME" + ableRowId + "']";

     test.Type(inTime, StartTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Difference * TableRowId)).ToString("hh\\:mm"));
     test.Type(outTime, StartTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Difference * TableRowId + Difference)).ToString("hh\\:mm"));
}
```